# Подсчет записей в категориях

Tags: mysql

У записи есть поле `category_id`, где хранится либо один айдишник, либо через запятую несколько. Пробую через `in()` - но не работает в случае где больше 1 категории хранится в поле. Как лучше это организовать, подскажите. Может нужно делать главную категорию. А дополнительные хранить в другом поле.

```
public function getByCategory($id_cat - текущая категория){
    $sql = "select t.*, us.first_name, us.last_name
    from tracks t join author_tracks at join users us
    on  '{$id_cat}' = t.category_id and t.is_published = '1'
    and at.track_id = t.id and at.author_id = us.id
```

Comment: может все-таки, следуя рекомендациям нормализации, вынести категории в отдельную таблицу и собирать потом вручную как надо?

Comment: Лучше использовать другую СУБД, которая поддерживает массивы.

Comment: приведи к sql виду.

Comment: Относительно 1 комментария - категории итак находятся в отдельной таблице.

Comment: и DDL таблиц, будет проще отвечать

Comment: В первом комментарии речь идёт не о самих категориях, которые и так в отдельной таблице, а об их айдишниках, которые сейчас находятся в `tracks.category_id`.

Comment: То есть для связки еще таблицу track_id - category_id . В принципе неплохой вариант, не подумал сразу

Comment: Да, полностью аналогично таблице `author_tracks`. Это лучше, чем использование функции `find_in_set`, хотя и хуже, чем использование какой-нибудь настоящей СУБД.